# How to create a Clustered Primary Key index for SQL Azure code-first migrations?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to add a spatial column to a table I have in SQL Azure. When I try to create a spatial index on that column I get an error saying that I need a primary key clustered index. Fair enough, but the table I want to change is a parent table and I need to drop the corresponding tables and recreate the table with the primary key clustered index. This is easy enough to do through sql, but gets tedious when we need to recreate the database on multiple development boxes. So I wanted to manually edit the code-first migrations to do the heavy lifting. The recommended approach for SQL Azure is to make your classes inherit from Entity-Data so the code-first creation for my table looks like this:

```
CreateTable("sbp_ct.Tiles", c => new {
    Id = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128, annotations: new Dictionary<string, AnnotationValues > {
            {
                "ServiceTableColumn",
                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue: "Id")
            },
        }),
    X = c.Int(nullable: false),
    Y = c.Int(nullable: false),
    SubAreaId = c.String(maxLength: 128),
    Version = c.Binary(nullable: false, fixedLength: true,
        timestamp: true, storeType: "rowversion", annotations: new Dictionary <
        string, AnnotationValues > {
            {
                "ServiceTableColumn",
                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue:
                    "Version")
            },
        }),
    CreatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7, annotations: new Dictionary <
        string, AnnotationValues > {
            {
                "ServiceTableColumn",
                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue:
                    "CreatedAt")
            },
        }),
    UpdatedAt = c.DateTimeOffset(precision: 7, annotations: new Dictionary <
        string, AnnotationValues > {
            {
                "ServiceTableColumn",
                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue:
                    "UpdatedAt")
            },
        }),
    Deleted = c.Boolean(nullable: false, annotations: new Dictionary <
        string, AnnotationValues > {
            {
                "ServiceTableColumn",
                new AnnotationValues(oldValue: null, newValue:
                    "Deleted")
            },
        }),
    })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
    .ForeignKey("sbp_ct.SubAreas", t => t.SubAreaId)
    .Index(t => t.SubAreaId)
    .Index(t => t.CreatedAt, clustered: true);
```

I thought removing clustered:true from the CreatedAt index would work, but the PrimaryKey does not become a clustered index. "clustered:true" is set by default for the PrimaryKey method but it still doesn't change anything.

How do I force a primary key clustered index to be created on a CreateTable method in a code-first migration?

I'm using EnitityFramework v6.1.1

Here's my model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace sbp_ctService.Models
{
    public class Tile : EntityData
    {
        public Tile()
        {
            TestSets = new List<TestSet>();
        }

        [Required(ErrorMessage="X tile coordinate cannot be empty.")]
        public int X { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Y tile coordinate cannot be empty.")]
        public int Y { get; set; }

        public DbGeometry Geometry { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string SubAreaId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual SubArea SubArea { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<TestSet> TestSets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The classes need to inherit from EntityData to play well with SQL Azure. They say to use it in all of their tutorials, for example [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-leaderboard/). It's basically a class that adds an ID, CreatedAt, UpdatedAt, and Deleted field and presumably helps create the clustered index on the CreatedAt column automatically. That's what I'm actually trying to override.

Comment: Hi, by default EF6 should give you a clustered primary key. Looking at the annotations in your migration it seems like you are using some kind of framework? You also mentioned inheriting from Entity-Data but I'm not sure what that is... any chance you could post the code from your EF model?

Comment: @RowanMiller I've updated it with one of my models. EntityData comes from Azure Mobile Services SDK which is open source. I wish I could have found the EntityData class in their repo, but for some reason I could not. https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services